Trying to programmatically disconnect microbit Pin
I am trying to set up a lab for students to investigate capacitance via measuring voltage drop over a capacitor using a microbit. I have a microbit hooked up to a breadboard with a capacitor hooked up in parallel with an LED/resistor. The idea is to kill power on the pin powering the circuit and have students watch the LED slowly dim, while the microbit records the capacitor voltage every half second. I am having trouble programmatically disconnecting pin 1 on the microbit. I have connected the same circuit to an arduino and successfully done this, but have been unable to translate the code to microbit. If I just use digitalWrite to set the voltage to 0, that instantly drains my capacitor, while if I use setPull, the light never dims and power is never killed. I have an image of my circuit setup and all of my code in python (which is where the issue lies).
time = 0
# pins.set_pull(DigitalPin.P1, PinPullMode.PULL_DOWN)
pins.digital_write_pin(DigitalPin.P1, 0)
pause(2000)
# pins.set_pull(DigitalPin.P1, PinPullMode.PULL_UP)
pins.digital_write_pin(DigitalPin.P1, 1)
pause(2000)

def on_forever():
    global time
    pins.set_pull(AnalogPin.P1, PinPullMode.PULL_NONE)
    # pins.digitalWritePin(DigitalPin.P1, 0)
    time = 0
    for index in range(15):
        serial.write_number(6)
        basic.show_number(pins.analog_read_pin(AnalogPin.P0))        
        datalogger.log(datalogger.create_cv("A", time))
        datalogger.log(datalogger.create_cv("B", pins.analog_read_pin(AnalogPin.P0)))
        time += 500
        pause(500)
basic.forever(on_forever)

The arduino code that successfully does this task is below:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
}
bool first = true;
void loop() {
  int data[20]  = {0};
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  if (first)
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      data[i] = analogRead(A1);
      Serial.print(data[i]/1023. * 5.);
      Serial.print(",");
      delay(500);
    }
  first = false;
}



You need to reconfigure the pin as an input.  As long as it's configured as an output, it's going to be strongly pulling the pin either up or down.

@jasonharper Do you know how to do this on a microbit? I know this is the issue, but I can't seem to find what I actually need to do in order to set that mode. The setPull() function seems like it should do the same thing as setting an arduino pin to input/output, but I haven't had any luck messing around with it

It looks like you call .read_digital() to set a pin to input mode.  (You'd ignore the returned value in this case.)

This was it. Thank you

I just needed to do a readDigital() on pin 1 in order to switch it to an input

I read the code again and I think I figured it out:
Looks like you might be referring to pin 1 by the wrong pin constant inside the pins.set_pull() call inside on_forever().
-pins.set_pull(AnalogPin.P1, PinPullMode.PULL_NONE)
+pins.set_pull(DigitalPin.P1, PinPullMode.PULL_NONE)

On some microcontrollers, the analog pins are referred to by their ADC channel number, not the digital pin number. Passing the analog pin constant may be confusing set_pull() which probably wants a digital pin.
You would think that micropython would have taken care of this analog-digital pin number mismatch, but it looks to not be perfect.

Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately this did not fix my problem

It might be that the pin 1 is damaged in some way, did you try other pins? You could also try asking in the EE stack exchange

I have a class set of microbits and swapped out a few different boards to rule out any hardware failures
